move_base_flex with separate global planner
I’m using move_base_flex (mbf) for my navigation as my robot needs to be able to follow custom paths or a path generated by a global planner. So, when the robot should follow a custom path, I use mbf’s ExePath Action and when it should follow a generated path, I use the MoveBase Action.
I want both the custom and the generated paths to always be visible in rviz. For the custom paths that is no problem as I generate and publish them myself. The problem is that, when I cancel a MoveBase Action to call an ExePath Action, mbf’s global planner stops generating its path. So, when I start following a custom path, the generated path is no longer visible.
I thought about initializing a separate global planner, which is only there for visualization. But I don’t really want 2 global planners to be running.
Instead of using the MoveBase Action I could also subscribe to the path of a separate global planner in my node and call an ExePath Action with the generated path, when I want to follow it. So, the path is always generated, and I don’t have 2 global planners running. However, I feel like this is solution does not really satisfy me.
Ideally, I want a separate global planner that always publishes a path. When I call a MoveBase Action, mbf’s local planner should just uses this path for planning. Do you have some kind of solution for this?
Thank you in advance.
